# How to share a $scope.variable with a child scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an audio player and am using this range slider - which works quite well.
https://github.com/danielcrisp/angular-rangeslider/blob/master/angular.rangeSlider.js

```
<li ng-controller="PlayerCtrl" style="display:inline-block;"> 
...   
<span range-slider min="0" max="100" ng-controller="PositionCtrl" model-max="position" pin-handle="min" filter="positionSilderText">
...
</li>
```

So I make a new Controller PositionCtrl inside the PlayerCtrl like so:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).controller('PlayerCtrl', ['$scope','$timeout',function($scope,$timeout) {
        $scope.audioTag=document.getElementById('audioPlayer');// an <audio/> tag
        $scope.position = 0;
        $scope.PositionCtrl = function ($scope) {
              $scope.$watch('position', function() {
                    if (updatePlayPosition && $scope.audioTag.duration) {
                        $scope.audioTag.currentTime = $scope.audioTag.duration * $scope.position / 100.0;
                    }
                    updatePlayPosition=true;
              });
          };
           ...
          $scope.ui=function() {//called by a $timeout
               ...
              var newpos = $scope.audioTag.duration;
              $scope.position = setpos;
           //   $scope.$$childHead.position = setpos;// <<-- dont want to do this
              ....
          }
    });
```

So initially the ui() function updates my slider pos using $scope.position and all good.

My problem is that once i drag the slider the position variable gets created in the child(PositionCtrl) scope and so the watch no longer finds the variable in the parent(PlayerCtrl) scope. Hence the slider no longer updates from the ui() method.

If i uncomment the line to assign the $$childHead.position then the watcher works . But its no good as i might add more children later and AFAIK you can't access child scope from the parent anyways (not sure why).

What is the correct way to share the position with both scopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be an inheritance problem again.  Check out the Inheritance article here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes.  Hopefully this will be of some help.  I THINK this may come down to putting the things you want to watch inside of an object (instead of $scope.position, do $scope.someClevelModelName.position) and watch THAT property instead of the position property of the outer scope.

Really hope this helps.

(Posting here for SO)

Answer (score 0):

you can always use `$scope.$parent`, or if you don't want to, you can define a function in the parent scope to update the required variable and then call it from inside the child scope

```
app.controller('Parentctrl',function($scope) {
  $scope.position= 1;
  $scope.changePosition = function(p) {
    $scope.position= p;
  };
  $scope.PositionCtrl = function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('position', function() {
      if (updatePlayPosition && $scope.audioTag.duration) {
        $scope.audioTag.currentTime = $scope.audioTag.duration * $scope.position / 100.0;
      }
      updatePlayPosition=true;
      $scope.changePosition(5);
    });
  };
});
```

I hope this is what you need

Comment: not quite, the ui() method is in the parent scope but the watch is in the child scope - so this wouldn't work. i need to 'push down' the position change from the parent to the child. Thanks though ..

Comment: did you try to make the position a global? it's a bit hacky but it does the job, instead of $scope.position, make it $scope.$root.position, then it will be accessible globally

Comment: still don't see how that would change things as the problem is that when i drag the slider the position variable gets created in the child scope - so the problem would persist.

Comment: my suggestion is to USE a parent created variable instead of creating a child variable and trying to pass it to parent

Comment: i am. the problem is tha the slider updates the model object it get duplicated on the child $scope - since i can access the child scope from the parent the $watch does'nt work. don't think your understanding what i am asking... Thanks for the time though.

Answer (score 0):

got an answer here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/eY1H2O7-vfg

I just had to put the position variable into a object in the parent scope.

i.e. use $scope.data.postion and watch data.position in the child scope.

there is info here:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes